# URL de origen del chat en Facebook Customer Chat Plugin

Tags: javascript, facebook, plugin

Estoy usando el plugin FACEBOOK Customer Chat Plugin en mi sitio web. Mi web ofrece productos, y el chat esta en el detalle de cada producto.

Yo respondo desde Facebook. El problema que tengo es que no tengo ninguún parámetro para saber de que URL viene la consulta.

Trate de usar el parámetro "ref" pero solo sirve para webhook. Traté de capturar eventos con javascript para "autoenviar" la url en el mismo chat, pero sin éxito. Ni tampoco puedo acceder por javascript al IFRAME del chat de Facebook que se integra en mi web.

¿Alguien tiene idea por donde puedo orientar mi búsqueda? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Le di un vistazo a la documentación del Plugin, y puede que esto te sirva:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin/#detect